# Extra odd symbols are added to serialization output

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, outputstream

I am trying to serialize a string object by writing my own code to get a byte array of that object instead of using *string.getBytes()* but I am getting extra odd symbols in the output as follows

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2HPY.png)

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Demo {

    private static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "D:\\testFile.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput out = null;
        byte[] bytes;

        String content = "Hello Java Code Geeks";

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(content);
        out.flush();
        bytes = bos.toByteArray();

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        outputStream.write(bytes);


        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outputStream.toByteArray()));
        System.out.println(outputStream.toString());

        // Write the internal buffer to an output stream
        outputStream.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE));

    }
}
```

PS: I should use *java.io.OutputStream* class  but if there is any other way to get a *ByteArray*  from an object other than my way or *string.getBytes()* feel free to suggest.

The reson of not using *string.getBytes()* is a need a general way to get a byte array from any kind of objects including user defind objects.

Comment: This sounds like it might be an encoding issue.  What character set did your source string have before you serialized it?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I declared my string as follows          
String content = "Hello Java Code Geeks";
How to know the character set that my source string had before I serialized it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read it as an object

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = null;
    byte[] bytes;

    String content = "Hello Java Code Geeks";

    out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    out.writeObject(content);
    out.flush();
    bytes = bos.toByteArray();

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    outputStream.write(bytes);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outputStream.toByteArray()));
    System.out.println(outputStream.toString());
    // correct string printed out
    System.out.println(new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray())).readObject());

}
```

ObjectOutputStream writes additional info to the file (e.g. class name and so on), these are probably the characters you are wondering about.